# How to create & maintain multiple "setWorldConstructor" in Playwright-API framework?

Tags: typescript, playwright, cucumberjs, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

I have created a Playwright-Typescript framework for API Automation testing. The application has multiple 'actors' like- Buyer/Seller/Agent and each have their own Cookie. So, the respective APIs need their corresponding Cookie for authentication.
Presently i had created a 'world.ts' file which sets the extrahttpHeaders in a class & through "setWorldConstructor"  its globally available.
My problem is, How can i pass Actor-specific cookies corresponding that API ? .

"world.ts" file is as below:

```
import playwright, {APIRequestContext} from "playwright";
import { World,IWorldOptions,setWorldConstructor } from "@cucumber/cucumber";
import { GlobalAPIResponseVariables, GlobalConfig } from "../../env/global";
import { env } from "../../env/parseEnv";

export type Api = {
 request: APIRequestContext
}
export class ScenarioWorld extends World{
    constructor(options: IWorldOptions){    
        super(options);
        this.globalAPIResponseVariables ={}
        this.globalConfig = options.parameters as GlobalConfig
    }
    globalConfig : GlobalConfig
    globalAPIResponseVariables:GlobalAPIResponseVariables
    api!: Api 


    async init(): Promise<Api>{
        const request = await this.newRequest()
        this.api = {request }
        return this.api
    }
    
    private newRequest = async (): Promise<APIRequestContext> =>{
       
        const request = await playwright.request.newContext({
            extraHTTPHeaders : {
                  'Content-type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                  
                  "Cookie": env('cookieID')
            }
        })
        return request
    }

    
}

setWorldConstructor(ScenarioWorld)
```

Answer (score 0):

To your custom world, add a variable, let's call it `apiCookie`:

```js
export class ScenarioWorld extends World {
    ...
    apiCookie = null

    set apiCookie(cookie){
        this.apiCookie = cookie
    }
    ...
}

setWorldConstructor(ScenarioWorld)
```

Note: Only using a setter in case there is more to your transformation

If you've set your world constructor, then as long as you are utilising cucumber, within `Before` and `After` hooks and `Given`, `When` and `Then` definitions, you can use `this` to access your world properties:

```js
Given("I log in as {string}", async function(user){
    this.apiCookie = new Cookie().for(user) 
    ...
})
```

The `Given` example assumes you've got a custom Cookie class for your Page Object Model with a "for" function that returns the cookie data that you are looking for

Note: the examples are in standard JS, but should help structure the TS code

It's your choice as to whether you tag your tests with the type of user, and run a different tag-based Before hook to set the right cookie before hitting the login, or whether you'll want to go through a step definition